# How do I call the Ubuntu system to open or save a file dialog box like Windows

Tags: 14.04, c

I'm using C# and I want to do something like Windows that pops up when I click save as, but I don't know how to do that

Thank you for all your help.
I'm sorry my English is poor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a [Gtk.FileChooserDialog](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AGtk.FileChooserDialog)

```
Gtk.FileChooserDialog Class
```

> Gtk.FileChooserDialog is a dialog box suitable for use with
>   "File/Open" or "File/Save as" commands. This widget works by putting a
>   Gtk.FileChooserWidget inside a Gtk.Dialog. It exposes the
>   Gtk.FileChooser interface, so you can use all of the Gtk.FileChooser
>   functions on the file chooser dialog as well as those for Gtk.Dialog.

```
public class MainWindow: Gtk.Window {

    protected virtual void OnBtnLoadFileClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Gtk.FileChooserDialog fc=
        new Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Choose the file to open",
                                    this,
                                    FileChooserAction.Open,
                                    "Cancel",ResponseType.Cancel,
                                    "Open",ResponseType.Accept);

        if (fc.Run() == (int)ResponseType.Accept) 
        {
            System.IO.FileStream file=System.IO.File.OpenRead(fc.Filename);
            file.Close();
        }
        //Don't forget to call Destroy() or the FileChooserDialog window won't get closed.
        fc.Destroy();
    }
```

Read more about here: http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AGtk.FileChooserDialog